# Error while loading spacy model AttributeError: module 'msgpack._unpacker' has no attribute 'unpack'

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, python-3.6, spacy, msgpack

I have a problem while loading model for spacy 2.0.8, but the same happens for previous version 2.0.7. Do you have any ideas what's going on?

Thanks in advance

```
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg', disable=['ner'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 19, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 113, in load_model
    return load_model_from_link(name, **overrides)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 132, in load_model_from_link
    return cls.load(**overrides)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/data/en_core_web_lg/__init__.py", line 12, in load
    return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 177, in load_model_from_init_py
    return load_model_from_path(data_path, meta, **overrides)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 159, in load_model_from_path
    return nlp.from_disk(model_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 638, in from_disk
    util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 522, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 625, in <lambda>
    ('vocab', lambda p: self.vocab.from_disk(p)),
  File "vocab.pyx", line 383, in spacy.vocab.Vocab.from_disk
  File "vectors.pyx", line 372, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 522, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "vectors.pyx", line 350, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk.load_key2row
  File "vectors.pyx", line 351, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk.load_key2row
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msgpack_numpy.py", line 179, in unpack
    return _unpacker.unpack(stream, encoding=encoding, **kwargs)
AttributeError: module 'msgpack._unpacker' has no attribute 'unpack'
```

Comment: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2015

Answer (score 3):

msgpack was just bumped to v0.5.5 ~8 hours ago.

In [Commit da902f9](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python/commit/da902f9c1d996fb461f1efef6487ef40d32d365a#diff-82bf3c7d2bf3fc852729c754ffa93870) the `unpack` function was moved from *msgpack/_unpacker.pyx* to the msgpack init file. This change is in the latest release.

Installing msgpack-python v0.5.4 should fix it for now.

Comment: how to install 0.5.4 using pip?

Comment: The new version of spaCy ([v2.0.9](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/releases/tag/v2.0.9), released yesterday), now pins `msgpack-python` to `0.5.4` to make sure that spaCy doesn't download the newest version. So if you upgrade spaCy, the problem should now be resolved: `pip install -U spacy`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem should now be resolved: pip install -U spacy.

Comment: Worked by upgrading from `2.0.5` to `2.0.9`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any other python files named 'spacy'.
hange filename if available